# jQuery object outputting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I'm having a hard time having a function return the output using innerHTML call in JavaScript.

It is outputting as 'Undefined':
[image]

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
    });

    $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(items) {
        console.log(items);
        var result = items.map(item => {
            return {
                Title: item.Title,
                Description: item.Description,
                Link: item.Link
            }
        });
        var $table = roadMapDisplay(result);
        console.log($table);
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = $table.innerHTML;
    });

    function roadMapDisplay(items) {

        var table = $('<table/>');

        items.forEach(item => {
            table.append('<tr/>');
            table.append(`<td>${item.Title}</td>`);
            table.append(`<td>${item.Description}</td>`);
            table.append(`<td>${item.Link}</td>`);
        });

        return table;
        
    } 
});
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>

<script src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/SiteAssets/roadmap.js?v=1"></script>
```

I want it to output the results from roadMapdisplay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a DOM Element property, and not directly exposed by jQuery.  To get it use `html()` instead.

Ref. http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = $table.html();
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Taplar! It finally displays some data! but it's pulling in the "innerHTML" object which has all the data all together. Is there a way that I can pull the "Title", "Description" and "Link" objects only?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Is the roadMapDisplay not returning what you want it to?  If that's the case then that method should possibly be altered?  Also make a note that innerHTML on a table will not include the table tag.  It will only return the markup for the rows.  If you want the entire thing you need to use `$table.prop('outerHTML')` instead.

Comment: I was able to include `$('#title').html($table);` which made the table display as shown in this link: [link](https://i.imgur.com/PbnNKtK.png) - The output is perfect, but how would I be able to format it so that it's not beside each other but instead below?

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents  that's a different question, :)

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways! I was able to replace the table, tr and td tags with container, row, and p and it is working perfectly!